# Output streamreader differs from textline

Tags: c#, .net, filereader, streamreader

I have to read lines of a .log text-file.

When exaiming the output during the run it shows the text with '/' or '/0' and such in between the chars.

I have tried several reading methods (also read byte[] ) but this didn't solve the situation. I can't figure why it would do such.

This is the last form of reading I have tried.

```
 string[] fileLinesRaw = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(filePath);
```

**To be readed text-line:**

[image: Text-line]

**Output reader**

[image: The actual output]

Comment: seems like your writing each char as a string. \0 is the string termination char

Comment: Not writing, the output is the read line

Comment: Show how you read, reading non UTF-16 as UTF-16 (Encoding.Unicode) would cause that.

Comment: Sure, coming up

Comment: Try `System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("c:\\null\\temp\\a.a", Encoding.Unicode)` if that works the file is UTF-16.

Comment: This solved it, thank you. Please put this as answer so I can mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interleaved null characters like that indicate that the file is encoded with a scheme that uses 2+ bytes to encode characters, such as UTF-16.

`ReadAllLines` uses `UTF-8` encoding by default, instead:

```
ReadAllLines(filePath, Encoding.Unicode);
```